# Can I use the google maps javascript api to display both points and polylines?

Tags: google-maps

I am in the middle of a coding an asset map for one of my customers assets.

The database contain information as below in two tables

tblAssets

```
AssetID
AssetName
AssetLocation
AssetLat
AssetLng
AssetType
```

tblAssetLinks

```
LinkID
LinkType
LinkLat1
LinkLng1
LinkLat2
LinkLng2
```

tblAssets is used to plot the individual assets, these contain other information (irrelevant to this issue) and tblAssetLinks in their current application draws a line between  LinkLat1, LinkLng1 and LinkLat2, LinkLng2

I have managed to get tblAssets to plot loading the db as an xml array as below

```html
<markers>
<marker PrimaryKey="175223" NodeName="TQ88768407" distance="0.0123043158297526" lat="51.455662" lng="0.716716" Type="NODE"/>
<marker PrimaryKey="175221" NodeName="TQ88768405" distance="0.0175958000932205" lat="51.455498" lng="0.716893" Type="NODE"/>
<marker PrimaryKey="175226" NodeName="TQ88768411" distance="0.023174171700034" lat="51.455791" lng="0.716119" Type="NODE"/>
</markers>
```

This is the javascript i am using to load my points onto my map

```js
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

        var customIcons = {
          OTHER: {
            icon: 'images/other.png'
          }
        };

        function load() {
            //map.addMapType(G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP);
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.4555503, 0.7164931),
            zoom: 18,
            mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
          });
    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(map);
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
          downloadUrl("xmlgen_asset.php?lat=51.4555503&lng=0.7164931", function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              var primarykey = markers[i].getAttribute("PrimaryKey");
              var nodename = markers[i].getAttribute("NodeName");
     var ownedby = markers[i].getAttribute("OwnedBy");
              var nodeid = markers[i].getAttribute("NodeID");
     var type = markers[i].getAttribute("Type");
     var lat = markers[i].getAttribute("lat");
     var lng = markers[i].getAttribute("lng");
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))); 
              var html = nodename + "<br/>" + type;
              var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon
              });
              bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
            }
          });
        }

        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        }

        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
          var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
              new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
              new XMLHttpRequest;

          request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
              request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
              callback(request, request.status);
            }
          };

          request.open('GET', url, true);
          request.send(null);
        }

        function doNothing() {}

        //]]>

      </script>
```

I was wondering if there was a way for me to load another xml with tblAssetLinks to draw polylines as well as the points above onto the map?

Comment: Sure.  You can put them in a separate XML or include them as different tags in the same XML.

Comment: @geocodezip how would I go about this for polylines with another xml?

Comment: How are you creating the existing XML? I would suggest a "line" tag which contains "point" tags for each vertex of the line.

Comment: @geocodezip the following code is what is used to generate the xml file in the example above https://jsfiddle.net/fw6oscww/

Comment: I have also now created another xml generation script for the polylines which outputs the following https://jsfiddle.net/ys0hdrhc/ lat1 and lng2 are the line start point and lat2 and lng2 are the lines end point, these lines may not necessarily meet up with the points in the first post thats why they are 2 separate tables

Comment: The polylines all have zero length (`(lat1,lng1) == (lat2,lng2)`).

Comment: @geocodezip Thats because i was being a dunce when I coded it! called lat2 and lng2 for both sets! https://jsfiddle.net/93d62y3e/ lets try again

Comment: So what problems are you having parsing that XML to polylines?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a method for doing so most of the tutorials I have seen mention arrays for latitudes and then arrays for longitude

Answer (score 0):

To parse that XML, get each `link` element, retrieve their lat1/lng1 and lat2/lng2 attributes and make polylines from them (per the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple).

```
  var polydata = xml.getElementsByTagName('link');
  for (var i = 0; i < polydata.length; i++) {
    var pt1 = {
      lat: parseFloat(polydata[i].getAttribute("lat1")),
      lng: parseFloat(polydata[i].getAttribute("lng1"))
    }
    var pt2 = {
      lat: parseFloat(polydata[i].getAttribute("lat2")),
      lng: parseFloat(polydata[i].getAttribute("lng2"))
    }
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [pt1, pt2],
      map: map
    });
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yxu093wy/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51, 0),
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var xml = xmlParse(xmlData);
  var polydata = xml.getElementsByTagName('link');
  for (var i = 0; i < polydata.length; i++) {
    var pt1 = {
      lat: parseFloat(polydata[i].getAttribute("lat1")),
      lng: parseFloat(polydata[i].getAttribute("lng1"))
    }
    var pt2 = {
      lat: parseFloat(polydata[i].getAttribute("lat2")),
      lng: parseFloat(polydata[i].getAttribute("lng2"))
    }
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [pt1, pt2],
      map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(polyline.getPath().getAt(0));
    bounds.extend(polyline.getPath().getAt(1));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function xmlParse(str) {
  if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  }

  if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }

  return createElement('div', null);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var xmlData = '<links><link PrimaryKey="56669" OwnedBy="SWS" AssetID="30757610" distance="0.0161501151649766" lat1="51.455479" lng1="0.716877" lat2="51.455498" lng2="0.716893" Type="COMBINED"/><link PrimaryKey="45827" OwnedBy="SWS" AssetID="1386010" distance="0.024165762230059" lat1="51.455791" lng1="0.716119" lat2="51.455769" lng2="0.716060" Type="COMBINED"/><link PrimaryKey="92131" OwnedBy="SWS" AssetID="30757581" distance="0.0258313521247188" lat1="51.455750" lng1="0.716015" lat2="51.455734" lng2="0.716000" Type="COMBINED"/><link PrimaryKey="55871" OwnedBy="SWS" AssetID="30757590" distance="0.033043902136047" lat1="51.455833" lng1="0.715905" lat2="51.455853" lng2="0.715906" Type="SURFACE_WATER"/><link PrimaryKey="79135" OwnedBy="SWS" AssetID="1386511" distance="0.0387150798069927" lat1="51.455372" lng1="0.715662" lat2="51.455509" lng2="0.715598" Type="COMBINED"/><link PrimaryKey="55870" OwnedBy="SWS" AssetID="30757560" distance="0.039789930528151" lat1="51.455353" lng1="0.715646" lat2="51.455372" lng2="0.715662" Type="COMBINED"/><link PrimaryKey="79136" OwnedBy="SWS" AssetID="1386531" distance="0.0415342089389798" lat1="51.455051" lng1="0.717068" lat2="51.454903" lng2="0.716886" Type="COMBINED"/><link PrimaryKey="79062" OwnedBy="SWS" AssetID="1386001" distance="0.0424351462005461" lat1="51.455944" lng1="0.715768" lat2="51.455917" lng2="0.715723" Type="SURFACE_WATER"/><link PrimaryKey="2812" OwnedBy="SWS" AssetID="1385989" distance="0.042520172377456" lat1="51.455795" lng1="0.715615" lat2="51.455692" lng2="0.715767" Type="COMBINED"/><link PrimaryKey="4041" OwnedBy="SWS" AssetID="1386420" distance="0.043199028781749" lat1="51.456078" lng1="0.717043" lat2="51.455662" lng2="0.716716" Type="COMBINED"/></links>';
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Looks good! And I assume I can work this into my existing code from my OP?  I will play with this in the morning thanks for the help so far @geocodezip

Comment: I must be being an idiot! I attempted to copy this into my current scripting and it prevented it all from loading all together. I then copied the relevant parts from your fiddle into a html document of their own, and nothing :( http://pastebin.com/KqcstXZs what have I missed :(